# Errors when using ParallelTable inside a package

Tags: packages, parallelization, list-manipulation, contexts

I'm developing a package that contains a function that requires evaluation of an expensive `Table`, so I use `ParallelTable` instead. It works correctly, but always gives an error message, repeatedly, for each kernel, like this:

> `` Table::iterb: Iterator {mypackage`Private`m,1,mypackage`Private`nsrc$663} does not have appropriate bounds ``

How can I avoid this error? Do I need to distribute variables explicitly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The iterator variable in the package lives in the context that your package sets (in this case, `` mypackage`Private` ``), but the call to `ParallelTable` from inside your package does not distribute the definitions in your package, because the parallel functions only distribute contexts that are listed in `$DistributedContexts`. This is by default set to `$Context`, which will most probably be `` Global` `` if you're running the package in a notebook. So the definitions in your package are unknown to the worker kernels, which is the cause of the error.

Instead, change the function call to

```
ParallelTable[..., {m, nsrc}, DistributedContexts -> {"mypackage`Private`"}]
```

Distribute contexts that other symbols might depend on (you don't need to distribute `` System` `` and the current context).

Comment: Thanks... I'm new to writing Packages and this is a great help!

Comment: This really works! Tks. +1