# ParallelTable behaves differently when it is run inside a package

Tags: performance-tuning, packages, parallelization

I've been butting my head against some very weird behaviour by [`ParallelTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html), and its interaction with packages, over the past few weeks, and making relatively little headway towards even reproducing the weird behaviour in a stable way. I just managed to crystallize some of this behaviour in a clean format and I would like some help understanding what's going on.

Consider, as an example of a relatively heavy calculation that one might want to parallelize, the following sum:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
Table[
  Sum[
   BesselJ[0, 10^-9 k]/(n + 1.6^k), {k, 0, 10000}
   ]
  , {n, 0, 12}]
]

(* {5.67253, {etc.}} *)
```

If I parallelize this, even for something this small, it gets faster:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
ParallelTable[
  Sum[
   BesselJ[0, 10^-9 k]/(n + 1.5^k), {k, 0, 10000}
   ]
  , {n, 0, 12}]
]

(* {1.89187, {etc.}} *)
```

(Minor change in the denominator to avoid what looks like caching.) OK, so far so good. Now, suppose I wish to make this calculation into part of a package, which might look like this:

```
BeginPackage["package`"];
function::usage = "function[x] is a function to calculate stuff";
RunInParallel::usage = "RunInParallel is an option for function which determines whether it runs in parallel or not.";
Begin["Private`"];

Options[function] = {RunInParallel -> False};

function[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{TableCommand, SumCommand},
  Which[
   OptionValue[RunInParallel] === False,
    TableCommand = Table; SumCommand = Sum;,
   OptionValue[RunInParallel] === True,
   TableCommand = ParallelTable; SumCommand = Sum;,
   True, TableCommand = OptionValue[RunInParallel][[1]]; 
   SumCommand = OptionValue[RunInParallel][[2]];
   ];
  TableCommand[
   SumCommand[
    BesselJ[0, 10^-9 k]/(n + x^k), {k, 0, 50000}
    ]
   , {n, 0, 12}]
  ]

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

In particular, I have given it the option `RunInParallel` to decide whether to use a normal `Table` or a parallelized one. If I run it like this, however, I get much worse timings:

```
AbsoluteTiming[function[1.1, RunInParallel -> True]]
AbsoluteTiming[function[1.2, RunInParallel -> False]]

(* {31.465, {etc.}} *)
(* {34.5198, {etc.}} *)
```

Note here that (i) both versions are much slower than their non-packaged cousins, and (ii) all the speedup from the parallelization is gone.

To try and probe this a bit further, I tried to add some functionality to let me extract the calculation and then run it separately. That is, running

```
function[1.3, RunInParallel -> {Inactive[ParallelTable], Inactive[Sum]}]]
```

returns the calculation that it would have run, but with the `Table` and `Sum` wrapped in [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) statements:

```
Inactive[ParallelTable][
 Inactive[Sum][
  BesselJ[0, Private`k/1000000000]/(1.3^Private`k + Private`n)
 , {Private`k, 0, 50000}]
, {Private`n, 0, 12}]
```

I can then simply pop them open with a corresponding [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html) statement. However, when I do this,

```
AbsoluteTiming[Activate[function[1.9, RunInParallel -> {Inactive[ParallelTable], Inactive[Sum]}]]]
AbsoluteTiming[Activate[function[1.8, RunInParallel -> {Inactive[Table], Inactive[Sum]}]]]

(* {11.7112, {etc.}} *)
(* {35.7969, {etc.}} *)
```

the timings come out as something else entirely, yet again. I'm a bit baffled about why the calculation is slower through the package than outside it, but mostly it's the parallelization that bothers me: why isn't the in-package parallelization able to work as well as the `Activate[Inactive]` route? Why was the parallelization lost in the first place? Did I fall into a bug or something?

Any help in understanding this will be welcome.

(All of this run, by the way, on a 4-core 4-thread Intel Core i5-2500 with 4GB RAM, MM v10.4 over Ubuntu 15.10.)

Comment: In the slow running cases using the package are you getting the answer you expect?

Comment: @Ymareth Yeah, the output is always as expected. Some other calculations do have unstable ParallelTable output (different output for different runs of the same code, and different to Table) but I have yet to find a stable, boxable example of that.

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30817/5

Answer (score 12):

**In short, the reason is that `SumCommand`'s (temporary) definition won't automatically get distributed to the parallel kernels because now `SumCommand` lives in the `` package`Private` `` context**, not `` Global` ``.  This means that `SumCommand` won't get evaluated to `Sum` on the subkernels.  It gets returned as-is to the main kernel, where now `SumCommand` *does* have a definition, gets evaluated to `Sum`, which in turn gets evaluated to the desired result.  But all the evaluation happens on the main kernel.

Aside: Note that `` Begin["Private`"] `` should be `` Begin["`Private`"] `` so that private symbols will go into `` package`Private` `` and not into `` Private` ``.

#### Why is the function slow when in a package?

Most parallel functions, such as `ParallelTable`, automatically distribute the definitions of symbols.  (The notable exception is `ParallelEvaluate`.)

When you put the function into a package, the context of all the auxiliary symbols (such as `SumCommand` and `TableCommand`) change.  This prevents the distribution mechanism from kicking in.  Package symbols, which reside in contexts other than `` Global` ``, do not get distributed by default.  This is to prevent the *distribution* of package symbol definitions to subkernels, which would break packages which must also do initialization (such as loading `LibraryFunction`s) in addition to issuing definitions.  Instead packages should be properly loaded on each subkernel, which can be automated with `ParallelNeeds`.

Unfortunately I do not fully understand the  distribution rules for contexts though ... you can read more at [`DistributedContexts`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributedContexts.html) and links within that page.

This theory that the problem is that `SumCommand` doesn't get distributed can be verified by adding `DistributeDefinitions[SumCommand]` right after `TableCommand = ParallelTable; SumCommand = Sum;`.  This will make it run fast again (but it is not a good workaround, see below).

#### How to fix it?

I have never written packages which use parallelization, so I have no experience with this, and no experience with what the major pitfalls are.  But I would not use `DistributeDefinitions` the way I suggested above (which was *only* for testing the theory that the problem is with distribution).

One problem with the way `Block` is used here is that `Block` won't have any effect across kernels.  It only works on the main kernel.  Thus if we simply insert `DistributeDefinitions[SumCommand]` inside of the `Block` body, the definition *will* get distributed to the subkernels, but it won't get cleared on the subkernels when the `Block` finishes.  Instead it will persist even after `function` finishes. You can verify this with `` ParallelEvaluate[package`Private`SumCommand] ``.

Instead I suggest never sending the symbol `SumCommand` to the subkernel in the first place.  Just send `Sum` instead.  One way to achieve this is with a `With`-definition (instead of a `Block`-definition), which does a direct replacement of `SumCommand` within the body of `With`.

Here's the final code:

```
BeginPackage["package`"];
function::usage = "function[x] is a function to calculate stuff";
RunInParallel::usage = "RunInParallel is an option for function which determines whether it runs in parallel or not.";
Begin["`Private`"];

Options[function] = {RunInParallel -> False};

function[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{TableCommand, SumCommand},
  Which[
   OptionValue[RunInParallel] === False,
    TableCommand = Table; SumCommand = Sum;,
   OptionValue[RunInParallel] === True,
   TableCommand = ParallelTable; SumCommand = Sum;,
   True, TableCommand = OptionValue[RunInParallel][[1]]; 
   SumCommand = OptionValue[RunInParallel][[2]];
   ];
  With[{SumCommand=SumCommand},
   TableCommand[
     SumCommand[
       BesselJ[0, 10^-9 k]/(n + x^k), {k, 0, 50000}
      ]
     , {n, 0, 12}]
   ]
  ]

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

(To avoid the red colouring you might consider using a different name for the `With` variable.)

This version is robust and runs fast.

Comment: Hmmmm. Let me give this a whirl. In the meantime, would using a `DistributedContexts` setting help? Would it pollute the subkernels in the same way as the `DistributeDefinitions` route?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  I did play just a bit with `DistributedContexts` and I didn't quite get the result I would have expected.  So I don't fully understand what it does.  Finally I decided not to investigate further precisely because it would still pollute the subkernels.  That's because it is `Block` that restores the definition of `SumCommand` when it exits and `Block` won't work across subkernels.  So using `Block` (or `Module`) here is inherently problematic ...

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @szabolcs part of the problem is associated with the distribution over the kernels. But I think that is not only problem.

We can generalize the foo function to run in parallel and achieve the same performance as the unpackage code.

The code is much slower in the packaged case, because it is different and lot more complex.
If you create a function with the same instructions as the unpackaged code, you should get the equivalent timing and the same results.

For instance, consider only the serial case

```
BeginPackage["package`"];
foo::usage = "foo[x, test] is a function to calculate stuff";
Begin["Private`"];
foo[ x_Real, test_:False ] := If[
  test == True
, ParallelTable[
    Sum[
      BesselJ[0, 10^-9 k]/(n + x^k), {k, 0, 10000}
    ]
  , {n, 0, 12}
  ]
, Table[
    Sum[
      BesselJ[0, 10^-9 k]/(n + x^k), {k, 0, 10000}
    ]
  , {n, 0, 12}
  ]
]

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

which runs roughly the same time as the unpackaged code (using ClearSystemCache[] to ensure correct timing)

```
ClearSystemCache[]
res1 = AbsoluteTiming[
  Table[
    Sum[
      BesselJ[0, 10^-9 k]/(n + 1.6^k)
    , {k, 0, 10000}
    ]
  , {n, 0, 12}]
];
ClearSystemCache[]
res3a = AbsoluteTiming[foo[1.6,True]];
ClearSystemCache[]
res3b = AbsoluteTiming[foo[1.6,False]];
ClearSystemCache[]
res3c = AbsoluteTiming[foo[1.6]];
```

with comparable timing and exactly the same results

```
{ res1[[ 1 ]], res3a[[ 1 ]], res3b[[ 1 ]], res3c[[ 1 ]] }
res1[[ 2 ]] == res3a[[ 2 ]] == res3b[[ 2 ]] == res3c[[ 2 ]]

{4.5524, 1.92163, 4.38698, 4.38055}

True
```

Now, if we define an unpackaged function equivalent to your packaged one

```
Options[bar] = {RunInParallel -> False};
bar[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{TableCommand, SumCommand},
  Which[
   OptionValue[RunInParallel] === False
 , TableCommand = Table; SumCommand = Sum;
 , OptionValue[RunInParallel] === True
 , TableCommand = ParallelTable; SumCommand = Sum;
 , True
 , TableCommand = OptionValue[RunInParallel][[1]]; 
   SumCommand = OptionValue[RunInParallel][[2]];
 ];
 TableCommand[
   SumCommand[
     BesselJ[0, 10^-9 k]/(n + x^k), {k, 0, 50000}
   ]
 , {n, 0, 12}]
 ]
```

evaluating it and comparing with you packaged function (res2)

```
ClearSystemCache[]
res4 = AbsoluteTiming[ bar[1.6, RunInParallel -> False] ]

{ res2[[1]], res4[[1]] }
res2[[2]]==res4[[2]]
{42.4399, 42.0656}
True
```

All results are equivalent

```
res1[[ 2 ]] == res2[[ 2 ]] == res3[[ 2 ]] == res4[[ 2 ]]
True
```

Comment: The slowdown is not due to the added complexity.  It is due to the fact that the (temporary) definition of `SumCommand` doesn't automatically get distributed to subkernels.

Comment: @Szabolcs I agree that part of the slow down is partially due to distribution of definitions to the kernels. But, it appears to me that the major bottleneck is in the definition of the function inside the package, that is why I only consider the serial case.

The parallezed case can be easily addressed in the package by setting two definitions inside an If conditional.